# How to run a github action from command line

Tags: github, github-actions, github-cli

I need to run some Github action on my repository,
but the Web-UI gives me some trouble with branch selection.

How can i run action by command line?

Answer (score 2):

The [Github Command Line tool](https://cli.github.com/) has many options for managing actions.

to run a workflow, simply run `gh workflow run` which will let you interactively select the workflow and fill in parameters.

The only non-interactive parameter is the ref to run the workflow on, which could be specified by

`gh workflow run --ref <YOUR_REF>`

almost any other param could be specified in the command args, but most useful is the workflow itself,
so if i want to run the "publish_staging" workflow on the "rc-1.3.5" branch, i can just run

`gh workflow run publish_staging.yml --ref rc.1.3.5`